# casting a function pointer to const volatile fails on gcc only (not clang or msvc)

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, clang, boost-python

The following code uses boost-python to create a Python function callback. It compiles fine on clang and msvc, but not on gcc. The boost versions are identical.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

typedef void CallbackType();

struct TheStruct {
    CallbackType *theMember;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE()
{
    boost::python::class_<TheStruct>("TheStruct")
            .def_readwrite("theFunction", &TheStruct::theMember);
}
```

An even more simplified version, without boost:

```
template<class T>
void runner(T const volatile*) { } 

int main() {
    void (*varname)();
    runner(varname);
}
```

clang and msvc are happy. gcc tells me:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:6:19: error: no matching function for call to 'runner(void (*&)())'
     runner(varname);
                   ^
test.cpp:2:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T> void runner(const volatile T*)'
 void runner(T const volatile*) { }
      ^~~~~~
test.cpp:2:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:6:19: note:   types 'const volatile T' and 'void()' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
     runner(varname);
```

Why does this fail in gcc, how can I find such documentation myself in the future, and how can I get it to compile?

Comment: Is your problem Linux vs Windows vs Mac, or gcc vs msvc vs clang?  gcc is available for all three platforms...

Comment: @BenVoigt Updated the question to clarify. Originally thought it was an OS issue, but realized gcc on mac points to llvm. This is reproducible on OSX using /usr/bin/g++ (llvm) and /usr/local/bin/g++-8 (real gcc)

Comment: lldb? Maybe you mean clang...

Comment: @MatteoItalia aye, thanks for the catch. updated.